# libstdc++ - compiling failing because of tr1/regex

Tags: c++, regex, linux, g++

I have these packages installed on my OpenSUSE 11.3:

```
i | libstdc++45       | Standard shared library for C++                 | package
i | libstdc++45-devel | Contains files and libraries for development    | package
```

But when i'm trying to compile this C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tr1/regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int test[2];
    const tr1::regex pattern(".*");

    test[0] = 1;

    if (tr1::regex_match("anything", pattern) == false) {
        printf("Pattern does not match.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ -pedantic -g -O1 -o ./main.o ./main.cpp
```

It outputs this errors:

```
/tmp/cc0g3GUE.o: In function `basic_regex':
/usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1_impl/regex:771: undefined reference to `std::tr1::basic_regex<char, std::tr1::regex_traits<char> >::_M_compile()'
/tmp/cc0g3GUE.o: In function `bool std::tr1::regex_match<char const*, char,     std::tr1::regex_traits<char> >(char const*, char const*, std::tr1::basic_regex<char, std::tr1::regex_traits<char> > const&, std::bitset<11u>)':
/usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1_impl/regex:2144: undefined reference to `bool std::tr1::regex_match<char const*, std::allocator<std::tr1::sub_match<char const*> >, char,     std::tr1::regex_traits<char> >(char const*, char const*, std::tr1::match_results<char     const*, std::allocator<std::tr1::sub_match<char const*> > >&, std::tr1::basic_regex<char, std::tr1::regex_traits<char> > const&, std::bitset<11u>)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What packages should i (un)install to make the code work on my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the c++0x library support for gcc as I think Regex is not yet completed

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Comment: How can i find the documentation for the version on my c++0x? ... as i guess it depends on the version of c++0x, isn't it?

Comment: Added link of library support in gcc